# setOnApplyWindowInsetsListeners invoked only setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) but toolbar goes inside status bar in android

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, windowinsets

i am new to android i am facing issue when i have to control of window inset to check the keyboard visibility status,,when i tried using

```
viewBinding.etAmount.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->
            if (insets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.ime())) {
               }
            insets
        }
```

it got triggered only after adding **setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)** in activity ,,but by adding this my entire toolbar and bottomBar gets collapsed ,,toolbar gets merged into status..

i got stuck

Comment: By calling `setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`, you are saying *you* are taking responsibility for applying the inset to elements like your toolbar and bottom bar that you don't want to overlap with the system windows. So where do you apply your insets to the toolbar and bottom bar? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Add a listener**

```
view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {

         viewBinding.etAmount.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->
                if (insets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.ime())) {
                   }
                insets
            }

    }
```